# Citing equations from equation environment

Tags: equations, citing

Suppose I have an equation at some point in my document say

```
\begin{equation}
equation 1
\end{equation}
```

and latter in my document I reference the equation writing (1). Is there a way to reference this equation so that if I add a new equation before it my reference will automatically update to (2)?

Comment: Yes: add something like`\label{eq1}`, and in the text `\eqref{req1}`

Comment: See [LaTeX/Labels and Cross-referencing](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Labels_and_Cross-referencing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this:

```
         \begin{equation}
         \label{eq:equation1}
          equation 1
         \end{equation}

         The formula of X is shown in equation \eqref{eq:equation1}.
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few variants. With the `cleveref` package, you don'rt even have to ype ‘equation’ or ‘equations’. Note that if you load `hyperref`, it has to be loaded at the end of the preamble, but *before* `cleveref`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref} %
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather}
  \label{eq-1}
     I = \frac{1}{2}(a - b) \\
    J = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}
  \label{eq-2}
   \end{gather}

I want to reference eq.\,\ref{eq-1} or eq.\eqref{eq-1}, or reference \cref{eq-2}.

\Cref{eq-1,eq-2} show that…

\end{document}
```

[image]